# How to change CORS policy for hybride app which uses angular 6 ,ionic 4 as frontend and scala as backend?

Tags: angular, scala, ionic-framework

I am trying to use post method for login purpose, following code:

```
log(data){
    let vals =  JSON.stringify(data.value);
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
    return this.http.post("http://IP_server:88/mLog" , vals, { headers: headerOptions}).pipe(tap(
    res=>{ console.log('data: '+res) },
    err=> console.log(err) ));
}
```

I am getting an error as follows:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://IP_server:88/mLog' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic application(android, ios and ionic serve) work on local host. By default web api not allow request from different origin.

So you have 3 options :

1. Allow cross origin request in web api / server.
2. Setup proxy in ionic application [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html). I tried it worked in android not in ios.
3. Use ionic native http [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) (recommended) it will resolve in both.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 6, you have to use httpClient headers to pass with all end points headers. below is function:

```
  getHeader() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      })
    };
    return httpOptions;
  }
```

Call this function and pass httpOptions to all end points. Else you have to do changes at java side..they have to set headers for cross origin.

Comment: no I am still getting error as follows:

OPTIONS http:// Ip_server:88/mLog 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load http://Ip_server:88/mLog: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.

Answer (score 0):

Can you hit the url from browser & get expected response?
If yes then **NO need** to change UI/Javascript code.
Need to enable **CORS** filter from server side/Java code.

Comment: No, I am still getting following error, Action not found 404 in browser.

Comment: if you are getting 404 that means that service/page not available.
check whether any service available for **http://IP_server:88/mLog**. re-verify URL